# Cannot delete a folder that have the "The tag present in the reparse point buffer is invalid"

Tags: windows, windows-10, onedrive

**I have saw [this](https://superuser.com/questions/1597731/cant-do-delete-folder-with-the-tag-present-in-the-reparse-buffer-point-is-inval) post but I can't figure out anyway.**

I have a folder syncronized with OneDrive that when I try to open it, it says the error "The tag present in the reparse point buffer is invalid". If I try to delete it nothing happens. I tried to remove it also with the command `rmdir /S` and `del /R /F` but it still fails with the error.

How I can delete that dir?

*I tried also the solution mentioned in the other post.*

Comment: Why don't you try what the OP in the linked post did? Even if we didn't find out what fixed it, it got fixed.

Comment: Yeah I tried it. But it didn't work.

Comment: a) You should include that information in your question. b) What part of it did you try? it has a series of tests that could take half a day to complete & says sometimes you need to run it twice. If you didn't follow exactly what it says, then it's an invalid result.

Comment: I ran all the test once. So I'm going to do all the tests again?

Comment: Did you follow all the instructions to the letter, cold boot, power drain, safe mode, reboot after tests…?

Comment: Yeah, I tried all of it

Comment: Then idk, sorry. I've never used OneDrive.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To solve this, reboot your pc in command prompt mode and type `chkdsk /F`.

Comment: Make sure you run chkdsk /F on the drive letter that is having the problem.  Most likely it is c drive but for me I had to run it on my d drive.  And you can run chkdsk /F from a command prompt and it will schedule the chkdsk on the next restart (you don't have to reboot into command prompt mode).

Comment: Amazed how unstable OneDrive continues to be. I made the cardinal sin of renaming a shortcut added to OneDrive (new feature). Ended up with copy of the folder. However, whilst chkdsk reported some errors, chkdsk /f alone didn't work. Currently trying chkdsk /f /r which of course takes a lot longer

Comment: Doing `chkdsk` on a drive messed up by OneDrive does NOT help in my case.

Answer (score 4):

My own very late answer is similar to [that of alex3025](https://superuser.com/a/1625186/942116). The main change was that I ran two other procedures before running *chckdsk*.

The folder was on my desktop and this was backed up on *OneDrive* (i.e. the path was something like *\Onedrive\Desktop\FOLDERtoDELETE)

The entire process was:

1. Run *Deployment Image Servicing and Management* (DISM.exe) as an admin
   (<kbd>win</kbd> to open the Start menu> > start searching for "dism" > choose "Run as Administrator" from the left pane or right-click and choose this option): Run`DISM.exe /Online /Cleanup-image /Restorehealth`
   Note: This step may take a few minutes to start and up to 30 minutes to complete. It also got stuck in the middle on the same percentage for about 10 minutes.
   **Don't close the *cmd* window when you're done.**
2. While still in the same *cmd* window, Run  *System File Checker*:
   `sfc /scannow`
   Note: This step may take a few minutes to start and up to 45 minutes to complete.
3. Run Checkdisk with the Fix and Recover parameters:
   `chkdsk /f /r`
   Note: You will have to restart the computer, as chkdsk is run *before* lodaing up the main components of *Windows*
4. If the file is also stored on your cloud and sync is enabled, I would suggest that you delete it online sometime prior to the next step. In my case I went to *OneDrive* [online](https://onedrive.live.com/) and deleted the bugger.
5. While pressing <kbd>SHIFT</kbd>, delete the file directly to avoid the Recycle Bin.

before that, I had already tried several other methods described here and on Microsoft support and community support pages.

Through Safe Mode with both *cmd* and *Powershell* (using the *Force* argument in both of them, and after having taking ownership of the directory and all the sub-directories. Also through the *Command Prompt Startup Mode*, executing `DEL /F /S/ Q "filename"`.
Nothing worked.
 In the windows GUI I get no errors at all and via *cmd* and *powershell* I always got the above error message.

Comment: Did steps 1 through 3 and it made my folder accessible again.