# Force delete .git folder on Windows

Tags: windows, command-line, git

When trying to delete `.git` folder using `del /s /a .git`, I get this error

> The tag present in the reparse point buffer is invalid.

and this `rd -f  /s /q .git` results in this error

> The system cannot find the file specified.
> .git\objects - The directory is not empty.

So, what is the right command to forcefully remove this folder?

Comment: `rd -f` isn't a parameter i'm familiar with, and isn't listed in the documentation. Can you try `rd /s /q .git` ?

Comment: @spikey_richie It returns this message `.git/objects - The directory is not empty.`

Answer (score 2):

`del` only deletes files.

To delete folders, use one of the following:

```
rmdir /s /q .git

rd /s /q .git
```

That will delete the directory recursively without prompting.

Comment: Both codes return this message `.git/objects - The directory is not empty.`.

Comment: @Diaa I can't reproduce what you are doing. I have a `.git` directory and both commands delete it with no issues as well as other non-empty subdirectories.

Comment: How can I know that it is being used by another software?

Comment: @Diaa I don't understand what you mean.

Comment: Maybe it is not removable because of being used by another software. I don't know how to check.

Answer (score 1):

One of the subdirectories might be a special *reparse point* which allows a kernel driver to provide custom handling for the items inside, e.g. on Windows it is *possibly* the "VFSForGit" software which downloads objects as they're needed, instead of downloading the entire repository up-front.

Run `fsutil reparsepoint query .git\objects` to check if that is the case.

If you indeed have Git VFS installed, try using `gvfs unmount` to deactivate it. (Though in your case, it sounds like the driver is *no longer* installed; "invalid tag" means the OS doesn't know how to handle the specific subtype.)

In general, `fsutil reparsepoint delete` should be able to remove any reparse point.

Comment: `fsutil reparsepoint query .git\objects` says `Error:  The tag present in the reparse point buffer is invalid.`. `fsutil reparsepoint delete .git` says `Error:  Access to the cloud file is denied.` P.S. I have this project a local cloud folder. Also, `gvfs` is not recognized as an internal or external command as returned by the command line.

Comment: If you still have this issue, you may want to check out my answer to another question [link] https://superuser.com/a/1734952/942116. My directory was a reparse point, was on the Desktop and was backed up by the OneDrive cloud service.